# Convert angularJS directive to Angular typescript

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

There's this JSONEdit AngularJS directive: https://github.com/mb21/JSONedit which I want to use for my Angular (version 5) application. I haven't worked with AngularJS for ages since I've only used it when I was student in university and didn't really had an idea how everything works. Does anyone have tricks/hacks/tips how to easily convert that code so it would be easily used in Angular 5 application?

Answer (score 1):

I am so sorry but it is not possible for simple reasons.

The structure of angular 2+ definetly different from angularjs (1.x.y)

Another reason is that, there are any other directives/dependencies (such as jquery ui, sortable and bootstrap 3) used by that directive therefore you must convert them and import in right order as described in github.

In short, find an alternative and make some simple changes to make similar.

For example you can use this simple alternative
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ang-jsoneditor